# Term for Foreign Speakers of a language using the prepositions etc. of their mother tongue

Tags: prepositions, linguistics, mistranslation

One of the things I notice when conversing with people who have largely achieved full conversational English, is that they have the correct noun, verb and adjective vocabulary, but they frequently (relatively speaking) use the wrong prepositions, conjuctions and determiners ... but do so consistently.

My assumption is that they are transliterating the appropriate phrase in their mother tongue and insert the translation of the word that their language would use in that sentence ... but English uses a different word in that specific circumstance.

To be clearer this isn't a case of "they mis-remembered the word" - if challenged they would say that yes, that's the word they intended to us, and they can use the word correctly in simple usages ... but in this context their expectation of the correct overall translation of a sentence is incorrect.

Alas I can't bring a specific example that I've heard, to mind ... but a fictious example would be something like "Oh yes, I saw that in the TV".

Is this a known phenomenon (either of speaking a Foreign Language, or of structural differences between languages)? And does it have a name?

Comment: Perhaps "broken English".

Comment: As an illustration of the process in reverse: I knew I hadn't remembered the correct French idiom for 'on the telephone' in an early French aural lesson, and was told off  when I volunteered 'sur le téléphone' rather than act dumb.

Comment: @GEdgar - No, I wouldn't call it that. This is the sort of thing that I might expect to hear from an English speaker who learned an idiom that differs from the one I'm familiar with (for example, the British usage of "in hospital" where I, a US-an, would use "in _the_ hospital").

Comment: @GEdgar That's certainly not too broad a hypernym, and I'd guess the best answer available. I'd suggest Nordquist's definition (at ThoughtCo).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Even with my complete lack of knowledge of French, I'd see that and think "on" or "over", in the sense of "above", rather than the intended meaning...

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin Prepositions are notoriously ill-behaved. 'On the train' but not 'on the car'. 'On fire'!!? Who can predict where French and English metaphorical prepositional usages correspond? 'Arriver sur les 6 heures'!!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - You won't get an argument from me about that; I don't try to explain the "logic" of English to anyone. Mostly because I've more-or-less decided that there isn't any...

Comment: ... There is, but it's illogically distributed.

Comment: In IT circles, I've heard it called MTI, mother tongue influence.

Comment: A Norwegian family friend used to write "I hope you are by good health". We asked him if it was a literal translation of a Norwegian expression but he said no, he had just thought it was the correct English idiom.

Comment: Each mother tongue will make what are called typical mistakes in another language unless they really master it. (That would be true of, say, Chinese speaking Russian too). For many languages, we (interpreters, translators and language teachers) know what many of these typical mistakes are for a particular mother tongue. Another example: The French tend to use the present perfect to translate their own passé composé, until they learn/realize that passé composé, though it looks like present perfect, is actually simple past in English. Many Spanish speakers will say Thank**s** God, with an s.

Comment: @Lambie Perhaps they're praying sincerely.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for [linguistics.SE] This is not specific to English.  Polyglots, however proficient or when code switching, are always activating the same parts of the brain that are close next door neighbors with (?to) other languages.  Some transference may be overheard from thin walls.  See the CEFR for levels.

Comment: @KateBunting That's funny, because that IS a literal translation of the correct Swedish idiom "Jag hoppas ni är vid god hälsa." and I am pretty sure "Jeg håper dere er ved god helse." is also a correct Norwegian idiom. A bit formal or old-fashioned for my taste, but I could see someone writing it in a letter to family friends.

Comment: @jkej - That's interesting. This would be about 40 years ago and he was the sort of man who would use old-fashioned language. I see that _ved_ can be translated in various ways, so he must have got a bit confused (though his English was excellent).

Comment: This is an interesting discussion of the challenge that the English language poses to non-native speakers. As Edwin Ashworth points out, the use of prepositions is a feature that increases the power and flexibility of the language but poses difficulty to speakers of other languages:  getting on, off, up, down; coming off, on, in, out, round, up, down and so on are beyond the help of any conceivable phrase book. In most cases the foreign visitor can easily express themselves with less idiomatic vocabulary.

Answer (score 4):

The generic term for the influence of one language on another is *language transfer*. The influence can be negative or positive. Another term for negative transfer is *interference*. *Contrastive Analysis* is the term for the study of cross-language influence.

Here is an extract from the Wikipedia page on *language transfer*:

> For example, in English, a preposition is used before a day of the
> week: "I'm going to the beach on Friday." In Spanish, instead of a
> preposition the definite article is used: "Voy a la playa el viernes."
> Novice Spanish students who are native English-speakers may produce a
> transfer error and use a preposition when it is not necessary because
> of their reliance on English.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_transfer

Comment: They are not always transferring. They can also just be guessing.

Comment: @Lambie. That is certainly true. But when a German native speaker, who has otherwise very good English says, for example,  "_I tell him when I see him_", this is most probably negative transfer. (Germans typically use the present tense not the future with _will_ in such contexts.)

Comment: Many foreign speakers don't know how to use will. That's a typical mistake, then for German. I'm relying on you, as I do not speak German. Well, in English, you can say: I'm going to the beach Friday. No preposition in English. :)

Comment: @Lambie. Yes. Choosing the best verb construction to talk about the future is probably second in difficulty only to choosing the correct article (or neither).

Comment: The correct term for the misapplication, according to the Wikipedia article, is not just 'transfer' but 'negative transfer'.

Comment: @Shoe I'm still wondering why we were taught 'If a person should wish to succeed, he would have to work as hard as he could' was considered an incorrect version of  'If a person should wish to succeed, he would have to work as hard as he can' by some academics.

Comment: @Lambie In _US_ English. In British English, you do need a preposition in that context: _on_ Friday. Aren't languages fun? :-)

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff. Indeed they are. Germans quite rightly ask in the Apotheke: "Haben Sie etwas __gegen__ Halsschmerzen?" (__against__ a sore throat) whereas Britons ask "Do you have anything __for__ a sore throat?"

Comment: These are errors. You have described the how, not the what: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_(linguistics)

Comment: The influence but not the mistakes or errors.

Answer (score -1):

People speak sometimes of "*[literal translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_translation)*".

[Essential Dutch Grammar: Teach Yourself
Gerdi Quist, ‎Dennis Strik · 2012](https://books.google.fr/books?id=B-g99C-FEdYC&pg=PT192&lpg=PT192&dq=litt%C3%A9ral+translation+of+the+prepositions&source=bl&ots=-USmgHz8JW&sig=ACfU3U22h5Shd8RwIS5zBznMP42W7hWmeg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3rtuY4K2EAxW3UqQEHZQnChgQ6AF6BQjJAhAD#v=onepage&q=litt%C3%A9ral%20translation%20of%20the%20prepositions&f=false)

[Reconnaissance des procédés de traduction sous- ...
HAL Thèses Y Zhai · 2019](https://theses.hal.science/tel-02460548/document)

[bad practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_translation)

> Bad practice
> The term literal translation implies that it is probably full of errors, since the translator has made no effort to (or is unable to) convey correct idioms or shades of meaning, for example, but it can also be a useful way of seeing how words are used to convey meaning in the source language.
>
> Examples
>
> A literal English translation of the German phrase "Ich habe Hunger" would be "I have hunger" in English, but this is clearly not a phrase that would generally be used in English, even though its meaning might be clear.

Comment: Franchement, ça fatigue. When you speak a language pretty fluently as the OP said, you are not doing literal translation. Literal translation is a term from the field of translation but of course a person could translate this or that literally in speech. This phenomenon is called making typical mistakes.

Comment: @Lambie If you could just for once be specific! I don't know what your "ça" stands for, and I've spoken that language (French) for a long time. The term "typical mistakes" is a far more general term than "literal translation", and then you don't have to be a professional in order to make translations, Why revert to broad generalizations when you dispose of precise terms? It is usual to explain an erroneous word issued from a foreign speaker  by saying it is a literal translation, ([bad practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_translation)).

Comment: Do translations; do them, not make them. Here are some more things: dispose of, issued from and, most likely precise instead of specific. literal translation is not a term used in language teaching. It comes from the field of translation. But like I said, a person can translate some x literally, yes. but this is not "called that". Here they say common (I say typical): https://www.londonschool.com/blog/common-french-speaker-mistakes-in-english-and-how-to-avoid-them-or-fixing-franglais/

Comment: @Lambie It is evident that you are carelessly over prescriptive when you insist on eradicating "make" from this usage: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+translations%2Cmake+translations&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3
Two recent examples: "[Jewish Bible Translations: Personalities, Passions, ...
Leonard Jay Greenspoon · 2020](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jewish_Bible_Translations/B9j9DwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22make+translations%22&pg=PT284&printsec=frontcover) ... make translations of Biblical books accompanied with commentaries", (1/3)

Comment: @Lambie  "[International Construction Contract Law - Lukas Klee · 2018](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/International_Construction_Contract_Law/tMJlDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22make+translations%22&pg=PT511&printsec=frontcover) FIDIC may agree to let other parties […]  make translations and publish […]". Your commentary about "dispose", however, is relevant, and I must thank you for your patience, especially in the light of the fact that I believe you already, once in the past, corrected this very mistake in one of my sentences. For "specific", I can't agree: the OLD says  "detailed (2/3)

Comment: @Lambie and exact SYN precise". As pertains to the term "literal translation" I don't understand why you neglect the confirmation found in the Wikipedia (type of bad practice)? There is, for instance, this other [definition](https://gengo.com/translators/resources/avoiding-literal-translation/) which is a further confirmation: '“Literal translation” is a term used to describe a word-for-word translation that sticks too close to the source text. It is a translation that sounds unnatural in the target language, is usually hard to read and does not convey the meaning of the original text.'. (3/3)

Comment: I knew that you would do this. Quoting dictionaries is not where this is at, as they say colloquially in English. And this is right: “Literal translation” is a term used to describe a word-for-word translation that sticks too close **to the source text**. It is about text, not about **speech** as in speaking a language. AND I said that a person might translate this or that literally when speaking an L2, didn't I? Here is the idea, first language interference: https://www.fluentu.com/blog/errors-in-language-learning/